# How to set picture for uibutton when accessing it as subview

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, uiview

So i have a button in a view i know how to access it but i have no idea how to change picture on that button. Here is what i got:

```
for(UIView *button in [okvir subviews]){

        if([button isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]]){
                    UIImage *picture=[UIImage imageWithData:slika];
                    [button setImage:picture forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                }
            }
```

However that results in a error:

```
No visible @interface for 'UIView' declares the selector 'setImage:forState:'
```

I'm guessing that's because button is UIView not UIButton, any idea how to do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to cast your pointer so that the compiler recognizes it as being a `UIButton` and not a generic `UIView`. This is entirely safe since you are checking the runtime type of your pointed object, so you can be sure it is a `UIButton`.

Use this:

```
        [(UIButton*)button setImage:picture forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```